# SQL using sp_HelpText to view a stored procedure on a linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Anyone have an idea about how to use sp_helptext to view a stored procedure on a linked server? basically something like this. I don't have the credentials to that linked server to look at it.

```
EXEC sp_HelpText '[ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.storedProcName'
```

thanks ahead.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Instead of invoking the sp_helptext locally with a remote argument, invoke it remotely with a local argument:

```
EXEC  [ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.sp_HelpText 'storedProcName'
```

Answer (score 1):

sp_helptext [dbname.spname]
try this

Comment: This is the same answer, with less detail, as [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953952/3025856) from over a decade ago.  What’s the benefit to repeating it? When you have a bit more reputation around Stack Overflow, you’ll be able to upvote answers you found useful as a way of validating them.

Answer (score 0):

Little addition in answer if you have different user rather then `dbo` then do like this.

```
EXEC  [ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.sp_HelpText '[user].[storedProcName]'
```

Answer (score -1):

It's the correct way to access linked DB:

```
EXEC  [ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.sp_HelpText 'storedProcName'
```

But make sure to mention `dbo` as it owns the `sp_helptext`.

Comment: Regurgitating a correct answer with minor nuances is bad form.  Please add to the correct answer's comment or construct a unique answer other than the one('s) provided.