# Calling sp_help on linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named 'Application' on linked server (hosting server) in schema 'ID'.
I am trying to view the details of same using `sp_help`.

But I'm not able to do it.
The problem is: 
  1. sp_help is in schema `dbo`. (It is obvious!)
  2. But my table in another schema named `ID`. (e.g. select * from ID.Application)

- I've added linked server to my local sql server management studio.
  And tried:

  1. `exec [198.198.198.198].[sms].[dbo].sp_help applicantion`
  2. `exec [198.198.198.198].[sms].[dbo].sp_help id.applicantion`
  3. `exec [198.198.198.198].[sms].[dbo].sp_help sms.id.applicantion`

'sms' is my database on linked server.

Results: syntax error.

I tried: [SQL using sp_HelpText to view a stored procedure on a linked server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953471/sql-using-sp-helptext-to-view-a-stored-procedure-on-a-linked-server)

But my problem is 2 different schema.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work?

```
exec [198.198.198.198].[sms].[dbo].sp_help 'id.applicantion'
```

Comment: Great!.  quotes '' solved the problem. Thanks.
But generally sp_help works without quotes. Why quotes are necessary on remoter server?

Comment: According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335.aspx, syntax is: sp_help [ [ @objname = ] 'name' ]; SQL Server is just too forgiving sometimes. And sometimes not :)

Comment: @Aki Generally, `sp_help` expects `nvarchar` as input parameter so quotes should be used, even if in some cases it can work without it. Quotes here are not necessary because of remote server, but because of  having a schema name. `exec sp_help id.applicantion` without quoter would not work on local server either.